# Copying strings into an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Hello I can't figure out why a) this code errors on the last copy and b) in the debugger it shows picture[0] containing 0 to 4 then containing 1 to 4 (see picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T13u0.png))

```
char picture[5][5];
strcpy(picture[0], "#####");
strcpy(picture[1], "#####");
strcpy(picture[2], "#####");
strcpy(picture[3], "#####");
strcpy(picture[4], "#####");
```

When xcode errors it shows the following

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that you need a null byte to terminate the strings. (In fact, your last `strcpy()` writes outside the bounds of the array, invoking undefined behaviour.)  Use:

```
char picture[5][6] = { "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", };
```

This saves on the `strcpy()` calls too.

---

I commented:

> The compiler might well generate warnings if you change the 6 to 5, but I think it is required to allow the initializers (even though it would have to drop the terminating null bytes).  But it is a warning that you'd want to fix; it is showing a genuine problem.

In fact, GCC 4.8.2 doesn't even warn about the issue under fairly stringent compilation options.

Compilation:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror ols.c -o ols
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char picture1[5][5] = { "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", };
static char picture2[5][6] = { "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", "#####", };

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s\n", picture1[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s\n", picture2[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
#########################
####################
###############
##########
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

Comment: Thanks. Thought I tried the syntax you gave before and it didn't work (though it might have been also a null byte problem).

Comment: The compiler might well generate warnings if you change the 6 to 5, but I think it is required to allow the initializers (even though it would have to drop the terminating null bytes).  But it is a warning that you'd want to fix; it is showing a genuine problem.

Comment: Ya I fixed it though later on I really didn't use them as it was all in a for loop that would never go to the end. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In `C` strings ends with the character `\0`. So you shall reserve space for them by declaring the array as:

```
char picture[5][6];
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `char str[n]` it means `n-1` chars are reserved for you. While the last one is a '\0' char (terminator). If you overwrite the '\0' char, it goes on printing till it finds the '\0' in memory.

So modify `char picture[5][5];` to `char picture[5][6];`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using a function from **strings.h**, make sure you take care of "\0", otherwise you will always get unexpected output at the end of the string(esp. when printing with *%s*). The compiler wont give any warnings because it wouldn't find anything wrong. When you are printing with *%s* the compiler will look for "\0", and keep printing until then when you run the program. In fact when you are coping using strncpy, if have an array size 9 and you only use 5, the rest 4 will have **null** stored in them.